# WP options plugin setting not saving the selected checkboxes

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options

I am trying to make a plugin, so far everything is working, the problem is when its time to "save changes" the text are saved but the selected 2 checkbox didnt save so both remains unchecked.

Heres the screenshot, the inputed text in input type is saved so its working, but the selected 2 checkbox remained unchecked, why is this?

[image]

Here's my code

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
    register_setting( 'my-awesome-plugin-settings', 'map_option_1' );
    register_setting( 'my-awesome-plugin-settings', 'map_option_2' );
    register_setting( 'my-awesome-plugin-settings', 'map_option_3' );
    register_setting( 'my-awesome-plugin-settings', 'map_option_4' );
    register_setting( 'my-awesome-plugin-settings', 'map_option_5' );
    register_setting( 'my-awesome-plugin-settings', 'map_option_6' );

});

    function sort_post_plugin() {
      ?>
        <div class="wrap">
          <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php
              settings_fields( 'my-awesome-plugin-settings' );
              do_settings_sections( 'my-awesome-plugin-settings' );
            ?>
           <div class="title-set"><h1>SORT POST SETTINGS</h1></div>
            <table class="mytable">
                <tr>
                    <th>Posty Type</th>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Post Type" name="map_option_1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('map_option_1') ); ?>" size="50" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Meta Key</th>
                     <td><input type="text" placeholder="Meta Key" name="map_option_2" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('map_option_2') ); ?>" size="50" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sorts</th>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" placeholder="Meta Key" name="map_option_3" />Name<br>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="cb_name" name="map_option_4">Price<br><input type="text" name="metakey" id="metakey" placeholder="Meta Key"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php submit_button(); ?></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
          </form>
        </div>
      <?php
    }
     ?>
```

I hope you can help me, this is my first time creating a wp plugin. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just outputs empty checkboxes. You have to check each box's value and then set `checked="checked"` if it's true.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" placeholder="Meta Key" name="map_option_3"
    <?php // check whether map_option_3 was saved
    if(isset(get_option('map_option_3'))) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>
 />Name<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_name" name="map_option_4"
    <?php // check whether map_option_4 was saved
    if(isset(get_option('map_option_4'))) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>
/>Price<br><input type="text" name="metakey" id="metakey" placeholder="Meta Key"></td>
```

You should also make name and price into actual form labels, not just plain text beside the boxes. :)

Comment: Thanks, but this makes the page "This page is not working, HTTP ERROR 500", But it finally works when I removed the 'isset'. Thank you!